# Matrix inequality

Tags: matrices

Let $Z$ be a 3$\times$2 matrix, $G$ be a  2$\times$2 positive definite symmetric (covariance) matrix,  $\sigma^2$ a positive scalar, and $I$ a 2$\times$2 unit diagonal matrix.

Numerically I always see that

$$Z^{\prime}(ZGZ^{\prime}+\sigma^2I)^{-1}Z < (G^{-1}+Z^{\prime}Z/\sigma^2)$$

Is that true always ?

Comment: Yes, it is always true. Actually the left hand side is less than *either* of the terms on the right hand side, let alone the sum of the two of them.

Comment: @GordonSmyth can you please provide a simple proof

Answer (score 0):

For any nonzero 2-vector $x$,
$$x'Z(ZGZ'+\sigma^2I)^{-1}Zx \le x'Z(\sigma^2I)^{-1}Zx=x'Z'Zx/\sigma^2< x'(G^{-1}+Z'Z/\sigma^2)x$$